# Injecting stereotypical role implementations by IoC container

Tags: c#, design-patterns

*AN UPDATED VERSION with GitHub link is avalable [HERE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150961/injecting-stereotypical-role-implementations-by-ioc-container-2).*

---

I am trying to define a plug and play architecture which leverages stereotypical role implementations (Validator, Reader, Writer, Logger, Query, etc) by automatically instantiating associated services through a very limited use of Service Locator.

Demo code: let's say we have a query object to define some sequence of integers:

```
class IntRange : Query<IntRange, int>
{
    public IntRange(int start, int count)
    {
        Start = start;
        Count = count;
    }

    public int Start { get; }
    public int Count { get; }
}
```

We also have couple services to be instantiated and invoked by inversion of control container. One to validate the query before execution:

```
class RangeValidator : IValidator<IntRange>
{
    public Task HandleAsync(IntRange subject) =>
        subject.Count < 0 || subject.Count > 10 ?
            Task.FromException(new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()) :
            Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

And one more for actual sequence materialization:

```
class IntSequence : IReader<IntRange, int>
{
    public Task<IEnumerable<int>> HandleAsync(IntRange subject) =>
        Task.FromResult(
            Enumerable.Range(subject.Start, subject.Count));        
}
```

This code should magically print `10 11 12 13 14` after successful validation with matching service instantiation and execution:

```
foreach (var i in await new IntRange(10,5))
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

The following snippet reports `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`:

```
try
{
    await new IntRange(10, 100);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Autofac configuration used for the demo code above:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<IntSequence>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<RangeValidator>().AsImplementedInterfaces();

var container = builder.Build();
var csl = new AutofacServiceLocator(container);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => csl);
```

Here are the library interfaces and classes:

```
public interface IHandler<in TSubject, out TTask>
    where TTask : Task
{
    TTask HandleAsync(TSubject subject);
}
```

And its specialization:

```
public interface IValidator<in TSubject>
    : IHandler<TSubject, Task>
{
}
```

I have this helper class which aggregates all the registered validation services into one (insures all the matching validators to report):

```
public class Validator<TSubject> : IValidator<TSubject>
{
    public Task HandleAsync(TSubject subject) =>
        Task.WhenAll(
            ServiceLocator.Current
                .GetAllInstances<IValidator<TSubject>>()
                .Select(validator => validator.HandleAsync(subject)));
}
```

One more specialization:

```
public interface IReader<in TQuery, TResult>
    : IHandler<TQuery, Task<IEnumerable<TResult>>>
{
}
```

And an aggregating helper implementation (concatenates outputs of all the compatible readers):

```
public class Reader<TQuery, TResult> : IReader<TQuery, TResult>
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> HandleAsync(TQuery subject) =>
        (await Task.WhenAll(
            ServiceLocator.Current
                .GetAllInstances<IReader<TQuery, TResult>>()
                .Select(reader => reader.HandleAsync(subject))))
        .SelectMany(results => results);
}
```

Now the base class for the query to define validation, reading, and caching strategy:

```
public abstract class Query<TQuery, TResult>
    where TQuery : Query<TQuery, TResult>
{

    protected Query()
    {
        Data = new Lazy<Task<IEnumerable<TResult>>>(ExecuteAsync);
    }

    public TaskAwaiter<IEnumerable<TResult>> GetAwaiter() =>
        Data.Value.GetAwaiter();

    Lazy<Task<IEnumerable<TResult>>> Data { get; }

    protected virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> ExecuteAsync()
    {
        await new Validator<TQuery>()
            .HandleAsync((TQuery)this);

        return await new Reader<TQuery, TResult>()
            .HandleAsync((TQuery)this);            
    }
}
```

PROS:

- Reusability (minimum amount of code for query invocation)
- Extensibility (easy to add more handling services)
- Traceability (`ExecuteAsync` defines a central point to add logging)
- Query objects are serializable/model-bindable DTO
- Required dependencies are injectable to handling services by IoC container.
- Testable through LocatorService mocking (empty locator provides a reasonable default behavior).

CONS:

- It is a `ServiceLocator`.

Comment: It's an interesting concept, as usual ;-) but I have difficulties to imagine its practical usage. If I had multiple ranges and wanted to apply different validators to each range... would it be possible?

Comment: I wrote a lot of data access API and I have never been validating the same request differently :) It supposed to be used in, let's say,  ASP.NET web api Controller action: `[HttpGet] public async Task<IEnumerable<int>> Sequence(IntRange query) => await query;`

Comment: One could subtype query to customize handling though.

Comment: @t3chb0t I have cleaned up the solution - it looks a way better now: https://github.com/dmitrynogin/Cqrs.Base

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to edit the question and post the improved code?

Comment: @t3chb0t Yep, done. Still trying to brush it up :)

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to do my usual complaining about basic issues, things that *as a good programmer you should never get away with*. (I'm looking at you Dmitry and t3chb0t. >.>)

> ```
> Lazy<Task<IEnumerable<TResult>>> Data { get; }
> ```

Come on man, get those explicit access modifiers in there! Label that thing `private`!

> ```
> public class Reader<TQuery, TResult> : IReader<TQuery, TResult>
> {
>     public async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> HandleAsync(TQuery subject) =>
>         (await Task.WhenAll(
>             ServiceLocator.Current
>                 .GetAllInstances<IReader<TQuery, TResult>>()
>                 .Select(reader => reader.HandleAsync(subject))))
>         .SelectMany(results => results);
> }
> ```

That's just ugly. I *get* wanting to use expression-bodied members, they're *really* cool, but this just looks *bad*. Let's rewrite that as a non-expression-bodied method and create some intermediate variables, because I don't like seeing `))))` anywhere in my code.

Back to this:

> ```
> Lazy<Task<IEnumerable<TResult>>> Data { get; }
> ```

I don't like the name `Data`, I think `Result` would be a little more informative. `Data` acts like it'll be a more simple type, but you have to call `Data.Value` which just doesn't look right.

---

Now I'm going to complain about this idea in general.

> I wrote a lot of data access API and I have never been validating the same request differently :) It supposed to be used in, let's say, ASP.NET web api Controller action: `[HttpGet] public async Task<IEnumerable<int>> Sequence(IntRange query) => await query;`

Here's the issue I find with this structure: if I want to change how things validate for an `IntRange` then I have to create different classes that work off different validators, add them to the configuration and hope for the best. I really fail to see where this would save any time/effort, especially if I want to validate something like a `UserRange` where you cannot select an `Id` larger than the max user ID, I'd have to either add it to the constructor (which means load from the database each call) or add it to the `Validator` (which means load from the database, and I have no idea how many times that will happen, I'd hope Autofac would only use one instance of the `Validator`, but who knows. Certainly not I) and hope for the best. This just seems like a lot of overhead for largely simple tasks. *Oh*, and I have to register my `Validator` *and* `Sequence` with Autofac.

Comment: 1) `private` - Common, it is year 2017. We do not write code which is not necessary to write anymore. Actually, Principles behind the Agile Manifesto: “Simplicity--the art of maximizing the amount of work not done--is essential” (c) 2001 :)
2) It is a way easy to refactor by extracting methods when there are no local variables (Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code by Martin Fowler). One could say that these is how functional code looks like – when one does write code, it is more generally condensed than it used to be in days of old – in imperative era.

Comment: 3) Agree, Query.Result.Value is more readable.
4) I have never been changing how things been validated. Really :) It means that I have different query or, at least, different query parameter values – so it works fine. The same time, I have a lot of query reuse, so this what needs to be syntactically cheap. Multiple validators are totally OK – they all cooperate on the subject as intended – it is an extension point. And, in year 2017, I use registration by convention, so it is hardly to be an issue :)

Comment: @DmitryNogin [Jon Skeet recommends always including explicit access modifiers because it shows you *explicitly* chose the modifier.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479214/any-reason-to-write-the-private-keyword-in-c/8479246#8479246) ;)

Comment: I have explicitly recommended myself to use Scala as an example of common sense ;)