# Injecting stereotypical role implementations by IoC container - follow-up

Tags: c#, design-patterns

*Previous version is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150833/injecting-stereotypical-role-implementations-by-ioc-container). Sources are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/Cqrs.Base).*

I am trying to define a plug and play CQRS architecture which leverages stereotypical role implementations (Validator, Reader, Writer, Logger, Query, etc) by automatically instantiating associated services through a very limited use of Service Locator.

Demo code

Let's have something primitive implemented for the sake of simplicity - a query to define some sequence of integers:

```
class IntRange : Query<int>
{
    public IntRange(int start, int count)
    {
        Start = start;
        Count = count;
    }

    public int Start { get; }
    public int Count { get; }
}
```

We also have some services to be instantiated and invoked by inversion of control container. One to validate the query before execution:

```
class RangeValidator : IValidator<IntRange>
{
    public Task ValidateAsync(IntRange subject) =>
        subject.Count < 0 || subject.Count > 10 ?
            Task.FromException(new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()) :
            Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

And one more for actual sequence materialization:

```
class IntSequence : IReader<IntRange, int>
{
    public Task<IEnumerable<int>> ReadAsync(IntRange subject) =>
        Task.FromResult(
            Enumerable.Range(subject.Start, subject.Count));
}
```

Logging:

```
class RangeLogger : ILogger<IntRange>
{
    public Task LogAsync(IntRange e) =>
        Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Time taken {e.Taken}");        
}
```

This code should magically print 10 11 12 13 14 after successful validation with matching service instantiation and execution:

```
foreach (var i in await new IntRange(10,5))
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

The following snippet reports `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`:

```
        try
        {
            await new IntRange(10, 100);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
```

Queries could be model-binded in ASP.NET MVC (No way to make it shorter! :)

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<int>> GetSequence(IntRange query) => 
    await query;
```

Autofac configuration used for the demo code above:

```
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<IntSequence>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.RegisterType<RangeValidator>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.RegisterType<RangeLogger>().AsImplementedInterfaces();

        var container = builder.Build();
        var csl = new AutofacServiceLocator(container);
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => csl);
```

Here are the library interfaces and classes:

```
public abstract class Event
{
    public Exception Error { get; protected set; }
    public TimeSpan Taken { get; protected set; }
}
```

`Request` aka external event:

```
public abstract class Request : Event
{
}
```

And the `Query`:

```
public abstract class Query<TResult> : Request
{
    protected Query()
    {
        Data = new Lazy<Task<IEnumerable<TResult>>>(ExecuteAsync);
    }

    public TaskAwaiter<IEnumerable<TResult>> GetAwaiter() =>
        Data.Value.GetAwaiter();

    Lazy<Task<IEnumerable<TResult>>> Data { get; }

    protected virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> ExecuteAsync()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try
        {
            await this.ValidateAsync();
            return await this.ReadAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Error = ex;
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Taken = sw.Elapsed;
            await this.LogAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Which uses the following services and helpers:

```
public interface IValidator<in TRequest>
    where TRequest : Request
{
    Task ValidateAsync(TRequest request);
}
```

With helper:

```
static class Validator
{
    // Invoke all matching registered validators
    public static Task ValidateAsync(this Request request) =>
        Task.WhenAll(
            ServiceLocator.Current
                .GetAllInstances(typeof(IValidator<>)
                    .MakeGenericType(request.GetType()))
                .Select(validator =>
                    (Task)validator
                        .GetType()
                        .GetMethod("ValidateAsync", new[] { request.GetType() })
                        .Invoke(validator, new[] { request })));
}
```

Readers supposed to implement:

```
public interface IReader<in TQuery, TResult>
    where TQuery : Query<TResult>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> ReadAsync(TQuery query);
}
```

Where helper is:

```
static class Reader
{
    // Invoke all matching registered readers and concatenate resultsets
    public async static Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> ReadAsync<TResult>(this Query<TResult> query) =>
        (await Task.WhenAll(
            ServiceLocator.Current
                .GetAllInstances(typeof(IReader<,>)
                    .MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult)))
                .Select(reader =>
                    (Task<IEnumerable<TResult>>)reader
                        .GetType()
                        .GetMethod("ReadAsync", new[] { query.GetType() })
                        .Invoke(reader, new[] { query }))))
        .SelectMany(rr => rr)
        .ToArray();
}
```

And the last one for logging:

```
public interface ILogger<in TEvent>
    where TEvent : Event
{
    Task LogAsync(TEvent e);
}
```

With a helper:

```
static class Logger
{
    // Invoke all matching registered loggers
    public static Task LogAsync(this Event e) =>
        Task.WhenAll(
            ServiceLocator.Current
                .GetAllInstances(typeof(ILogger<>)
                    .MakeGenericType(e.GetType()))
                .Select(logger => 
                    (Task)logger
                        .GetType()
                        .GetMethod("LogAsync", new[] { e.GetType() })
                        .Invoke(logger, new[] { e })));
}
```

PROS:

- Reusability (minimum amount of code for query invocation)
- Extensibility (easy to add more handling services)
- Traceability (`ExecuteAsync` defines a central point to add logging)
- Query objects are serializable/model-bindable DTO
- Required dependencies are injectable to handling services by an IoC container.
- Testable through `LocatorService` mocking (empty locator provides a reasonable default behavior).

CONS:

- It is a `ServiceLocator`.

Comment: This looks so pretty and clean and I don't get it completely yet ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t We could go to chat or feel free to skype me (skype id: dmitrynogin). I would be more than happy to know what looks counterintuitive :)

Comment: I'll save your skype name and I'll get back to you when I'm done with my dependency properties ;-)

Comment: What does this mean `await new IntRange(10,5)`? I was under the impression that you can't await constructors. This is the first time I see `new` and `await` used together.

Comment: @NikitaB It actually awaits instance: it is enough to implement GetAwaiter() in the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After studying the code for a while... I am not sure if that is genial or absolutely over engineered ;)

Probably because I can't imagine real-world use cases for that framework. So, I'll try to solve a more real-world problem to see how it works:

**Problem:**

Loading lookup values form a database:

- There are lots of lookup values in the database (Table: LookupValues, Columns: Type (string), Key (int), Value (string))
- All lookup values with the same Type belongs together
- Each lookup value is a key value pair
- The number of loaded lockup values should be logged
- After loading the lookup values, it should be validated that the value properties are not empty.

---

**Solution:**

First of all, lets assume that the database access is abstracted by the following interface:

```
public interface IDatabase
{
    Task<KeyValuePair<int, string>[]> LoadLookupValues(string lookupType);
}
```

Lets start with the query:

```
class LookupValueQuery : Query<KeyValuePair<int, string>>
{
    public LookupValueQuery(string lookupType)
    {
        LookupType = lookupType;
    }
    public string LookupType { get; }
}
```

and the reader:

```
class LookupValueReader : IReader<LookupValueQuery, KeyValuePair<int, string>>
{
    private readonly IDatabase myDatabase;
    public LookupValueReader(IDatabase database)
    {
        myDatabase = database;
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>> ReadAsync(LookupValueQuery subject) 
        => myDatabase.LoadLookupValues(subject.LookupType);
}
```

The usage for the query would be:

```
foreach (var lookupValue in await new LookupValueQuery("MyFavoriteLookupValues"))
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {pair.Key}; Value: {pair.Value}");
```

That looks quite simple so far.

Ok, lets add the logger

```
class LookupValueLogger : ILogger<LookupValueQuery>
{
    public Task LogAsync(LookupValueQuery e) =>
        Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Loaded lookup values of type '{e.LookupType}' in {e.Taken.TotalMilliseconds} ms");
}
```

It is not possible to log information about the result.

Lets continue with the validator:

```
class LookupValueValidator : IValidator<LookupValueQuery>
{
    public Task ValidateAsync(LookupValueQuery subject) =>
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(subject.LookupType) ?
            Task.FromException(new ArgumentException("LookupType must not be null or empty")) :
            Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

It is only possible to validate the query, not the result.

Of course, it is possible to overwrite the query's `ExecuteAsync` method, and extend the API, but that is far away from being a simple usage.

---

**Pros:**

- I like, that the usage of the query is independent of the query execution logic. Just create a query object and it will be 'magically' executed.
- Same for the implementation. The query knows only its parameters but nothing related to the execution (at least from the view of the query implementer)

**Cons:**

- While IMHO it is reasonable to splitting the functionality of the reader and the query in different classes, I don't see the benefit of spreading the rest of the functionality (logging and validation) in multiple classes in general.

  - Logging can be done by the reader implementation if required.
  - The query is responsible for validating it's arguments - there is no separate class required for that.
  - It is NOT easy to extend if you have specific use cases!
- Like @Nikita B, I don't like service locators because they hide dependencies. Otherwise, I can not imagine another way to execute a query that way...
- There is a dependency to a concrete DI framework.

**Conclusion**

I think, at the end of the day, I would prefer a conventional DI approach to your nice query API.

Instead of

```
foreach (var element in new Query(/*parameters*/)
    // process element
```

I would just use

```
IReader<Query> reader = // injected by DI (with ANY DI framework and without ServiceLocator)
foreach (var element in reader.Execute(new Query(/*parameters*/))
    // process element
```

Answer (score 5):

I have a personal vendetta against `ServiceLocator`, so I can't judge it objectively and I won't. :)

What bothers me though, is your use of reflection. Why do you even need it? All DI containers I've worked with (Autofac is not one of those) had a way to do both: specify a default implementation of an interface and register a wrapper that would resolve a collection. So you should be able to register:

```
class LogAggregator<T> : ILogger<T>
{
    class LogAggregator(ILogger<T>[] loggers)
    {
        _loggers = loggers;
    }

    public Task LogAsync(IntRange e)
    {
        return Task.WhenAll(_loggers.Select(l => l.LogAsync(e)));
    } 

    private readonly ILogger<T>[] _loggers;
}
```

as default implementation and resolve it as `ILogger<T>`:

```
//pseudocode, I don't know Autofac API
await ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ILogger<TResult>>().LogAsync(this);
```

Comment: +1, thanks. Unfortunatly, `Query<T>` does not know the descendant type `IntRange`, so it cannot resolve `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ILogger<IntRange>>` in a generic way, reflection needs to help. We could go with `class Query<TQuery, TResult> where TQuery: Query<TQuery, TResult>`, so we have `class IntRange : Query<IntRange, int>`, but I would personally prefer using hidden reflection complexity over complicating library use.